# Short shiny silver threads in potted plant soil?

Tags: indoors, pest-control

I have an indoor potted plant, and I'm seeing this [very freaky thing in the soil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kofoe.jpg). It's hard to see in the video, and basically impossible to see without a flashlight or bright light shining on the soil, but the look like very short silver threads that are waving around. What are they? Are they alive? Is my plant doomed because of silvery space invaders?

Here's a picture of the plant:

[image]

Comment: what soil  did you use in the pot? new potting soil or something else? is the plant currently healthy(seeing a photo of the plant too would be good)

Comment: This was new potting soil mixed with compost. The plant seems healthy. Not dropping leaves or wilting or anything.

Comment: Also, I took a look at a few of my other potted plants and they all have the same thing. Not as many, but definitely there...

Comment: Compost? as in home made compost from a heap  or compost  bin? how do you produce your compost (turning twice a week til its ready  or not turning at all?)

Comment: We subscribe to Garbage to Garden, which gives us a compost bin and picks it up once a week. We can order a bag of compost when we like. It comes from [Rocky Hill Farm](http://rockyhillfarm.net).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?
It seems I am having the same thing in all of my pots but could not figure what is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see activity in the soil in your short video, but am not entirely sure what it is. I suspect whatever it is was in the compost you mixed in with your potting soil - if compost isn't sterile, it should not be used for houseplants indoors. You don't say whether the plants you used it for are healthy or not, but either way, I'm not sure I'd want to see that activity in the soil of my plants in the house, so I'd be inclined to remove the plants from their pots,get off as much soil as possible without damaging the roots, and check if you can see any similar activity  in what's left round the roots. If you can, soak the rootballs in water for an hour or so, swish them around a  bit then remove and repot into clean pots using new potting soil with nothing else mixed in. You may be able to see more clearly quite what's in there when you go through the unpotting and soil removal process too, but compost is full of a range of bio diverse organisms, not all of which are apparent to  the naked eye.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've done that with all the plants in my house. Sadly I didn't get a better understanding of what was going on, but hopefully this will get rid of them.